# Vs Code Small Guide

Tags: dart, visual-studio-code

Whenever i write code in Dart in Vscode It shows me guide about stuff I don't want to see
[image]

How can I get rid if this annoying guide

Comment: Please don't tag Visual Studio for VS Code questions.

Answer (score 0):

These are called Parameter Hints (and are showing you the parameters for the function you're calling). You can disable them with this VS Code setting:

[image: Parameter Hints setting in VS Code]

Answer (score 0):

You can close quick suggestions by editing settings.json. To edit settings.json go to Preferences->Settings page (Shortcut: Cmd + Shift + P and type settings.json)

[image]

Then add the following code (or edit if there is 'editor.quickSuggestions' key in the file) to close quick suggestions.

```
"editor.quickSuggestions": {
        "comments": false,
        "other": true,
        "strings": false
    },
```